# TO_DATE() is returning incorrect format than the format specified in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to convert the date I have got using the `GETDATE()` function into `YY-MON-DD` format such as `04 Nov 2022`. I have used `TO_VARCHAR()` to convert into the date returned by the `GETDATE()` into a string. The output is correct till the `TO_VARCHAR()` is used i.e. `SELECT TO_VARCHAR(GET_DATE, 'DD-MON-YY')` returns the desired format.

When I try to wrap it around `TO_DATE()` function; the date format changes into `2022-11-04`.

```
SELECT TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(GETDATE(), 'DD-MON-YY'), 'DD-MON-YY')
```

How can I resolve the problem and correct the format!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A date will display in the default format for your session. If you want to display it in a different format you would need to use the TO_CHAR(date_col, fmt) construct. So your select statement just needs to be:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(GETDATE(), 'DD-MON-YY')
```

wrapping a TO_DATE round it doesn't achieve anything if all you are trying to do is display that column as an output of your SELECT statement

Answer (score 0):

You need set the desired format at session level

```
alter session 
set date_output_format='DD-MON-YYYY';

select getdate()::date --getdate() returns a timestamp not a date
select current_date() --alternatively
```

As Nick suggested, use the select to format dates instead of tinkering with session parameters